# How to set class path for jdbc driver for postgres

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

How to install JDBC Driver for postgresql and  how to set CLASS PATH for JDBC drivers for postgresql on Ubuntu . I don't know how to install  JDBC driver and set class path for it can any you help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your terminal

```
apt-get install libpostgresql-jdbc-java libpostgresql-jdbc-java-doc
```

to download the driver to usr/share/java folder. Then go to your bashrc file

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

and at the bottom of that file add

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/postgresql-42.1.4.jar
```

It should work after that. =)